# Excluding certain results for SQL Query

Tags: sql, where-clause

Wasn't quite sure how to do this, but I'm sure it is pretty simple. For p.program_id I get several results such as OP, TEST, SA, INTAKE, etc and I would like to exclude intake, court, and test from those results. I would also like to do the same for patient_id to exclude our test users which I'm assuming would be the same thing. Figure it is some sort of exclude command to put in the where statement. I just don't know it. Thanks.

```
select 
    distinct p.patient_id,
    p.date_discharged,
    p.discharge_reason,
    pa.lname+', '+pa.fname as 'Patient',
    p.clinic_id,
    p.service_id,
    p.program_id,
    p.protocol_id
from patient_assignment p
join patient pa
    on p.patient_id = pa.patient_id
where (p.date_discharged between '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000'
                             and '2013-06-01 00:00:00.000')
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data of what this query returns and desired results?

Comment: Something called `id` should be an integer (I'm assuming it isn't since you say it has values like OP, TEST, SA, INTAKE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where  p.program_id not in ('OP', 'TEST', 'SA', 'INTAKE' )

Comment: That did it. Thank you. When the time hold is up I will mark this as the correct answer.